# Completely Remove Query Cache From CakePHP 2.x

Tags: mysql, cakephp, caching, innodb, cakephp-2.3

I have the follow queries taking place

```
 public function test()
 {
    $uuid = substr( String::uuid() , 4 , rand( 7 , 10 ) );
    $name = $uuid;

    $event = $this->Event->getEvent( array( "event_id" => "5240e695-9acc-4e32-9b98-1aecb3d0838" ) );
    $event[ "event_name" ] = $name;

    $this->Event->update( $event );

    debug( $this->Event->search( array( "event_id" => $event[ "event_id"] ) )[ 0 ][ "event_name" ] );

    debug( $this->Event->search( array( "event_id" => $event[ "event_id"] , "limit" => 1 ) )[ 0 ][ "event_name" ] );
}
```

I assign a random name to a particular event retrieved from a mySQL ( InnoDB ) table `event`, assign a random new name to it, and save it back in the database.

When I run the last two statements in this code, the results are not the same, note that the last parameter in the 2nd query simply adds LIMIT 1 to the end of the second query. ( I am not using CakePHP 2.x's typical methods for searching tables ). The result of the 1st search call will produce the previous result from the previous request while the 2nd search call will produce the actual currently updated name in the `event` table.

I've been searching high and low on how to remove query cacheing COMPLETELY from the datasource objects but can't figure out how. I've tried using flushMethodCache() on the datasource object, but it does nothing, I've tried setting

```
$cacheQueries = false, $cacheSources = false;
```

in the AppModel, but that doesn't do anything either. I've tried looking in /App/Config/Core.php and disabling cacheing, and setting the cache time to 0. None of this works.

Comment: what does `search` functions do? Can you post some code about it? Why you _do not use CakePHP 2.x's typical methods for searching tables_?

Comment: For security reasons, I can not post the internals of the framework but I can post the two query strings that these 2 function calls execute.

http://pastebin.com/YTFskNPF

Whenever the 1st query is modified, but returns equivalent results, the query returns the PREVIOUS results called by the Event model in the  `query` function, I've come to the conclusion that query is being cached.

I do not use CakePHP 2.x typical methods for CRUD because they do not entirely serve the complicated needs for the application I am building, as I need more customization in queries than CakePHP 2.x provides.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found out the problem:

Instead of calling

`$model->query( $string );`

I needed to call

`$model->query( $string, false );`

Comment: [Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query)